# Added TableAdapter not Visible

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dataset

I added a tableadapter in my DataSet.xsd, but when I go into code I cannot access it?

If I do

```
this.doss1TableAdapter1.Fill(this.tDataSet.kbpres, cboBeheerder.Text);
```

I get

> Error 2   'PerBeheerder.frmPerBeheeder' does not contain a definition for 'doss1TableAdapter' and no extension method 'doss1TableAdapter' accepting a first argument of type 'PerBeheerder.frmPerBeheeder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)